# java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException with limited Asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am getting

> java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task
>   android.os.AsyncTask$3@672f695 rejected from
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@25293aa[Running, pool size =
>   17, active threads = 17, queued tasks = 128, completed tasks = 165].

How to resolve issue?  Even i have just started 6-7 `AsyncTask`.

Let me know in which situations i can get above error.

Comment: Your asynctask is  serial execution or parallel execution?

Comment: Share your AsyncTask code